# Permission denied (publickey) after chmod server hom dir

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I can't ssh to my server on AWS ec2 after I made `chmod` to home directory of the server(I can't remember exact command I made to the home directory).

When I tried to ssh to my server, I got message like below.

```
...
Host '????' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Was it working earlier, before chmod to home dir?

Comment: It would help if we knew the exact command, as `ssh` is kind of picky about the permissions of its files. If, for example, you have given write access to everyone on the `authorized_keys` file, `ssh` will refuse to use the file, making login to the server by keyfile impossible.

Answer (score 1):

ssh requires the user used to login to server to have access to `/home/username/.ssh`. If you can't access the server with another user you can

- stop the instance
- launch a new instance with the EBS from the server attached to it
- login to the new server and adjust the permissions for on the EBS

Consult [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder) for the permissions you should have for the `.ssh` folder.

Answer (score 0):

AWS stores EC2 private keys in the /home/.ssh directory and you get the public key for that.
Now looks like you have removed access to /home dir, hence you are not even able to login into. Now there are two ways to fix this:

1. UI console for EC2 server -which AWS doesn't provide, I guess.
2. Try ssh from another EC2 server within the same network and region and correct the /home dir permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all the answers and comments.
And I want to share the link(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/).
The method3 was worked well for me.